# how to dynamically add values to an array

Tags: php

Here is the working script with hard coded values:

```
$subject->currentCert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][] = array(
   'extnId' => 'id-ce-subjectAltName',
   'critical' => false,
   'extnValue' => array(
      array('dNSName' => 'www.domain1.com'),
      array('dNSName' => 'www.domain2.com')
   )
);
```

I would like to update the above script (**extnValue section only**) to automatically take values from a another array called $OPTIONS["altnames"]

First I convert the following string to an array

```
$sans = 'www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com';
```

I converted the string to an array $OPTIONS["altnames"] with the following code:

```
$OPTIONS["altnames"] = array();
if (    !empty($sans)   ) {
    if (strpos($sans,",") !== false) {
        $sans = str_replace(" ", "", $sans); //remove spaces
        $sans = explode(",", $sans); //strip each value after comma to array

        foreach ($sans as $value) {
        array_push($OPTIONS["altnames"], $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do next

Comment: What's wrong with just `$OPTIONS['altnames'] = $sans;`?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the `array_merge()` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Get rid of the `strpos()` check. What if `$sans` just has one name with no comma, don't you want to put that into the options?

Comment: @barmar, yes i do want to add it.. ultimately, i want to be able to port over any values in $OPTIONS array to 'extnValue' array in this format array('dNSName' => 'www.domain1.com'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another level of array in the `extnValue` array when you copy it from `$OPTIONS['altnames']`:

```
$extnValues = array();
foreach ($OPTIONS['altnames'] AS $name) {
    $extnValues[] = array('dNSName' => $name);
}
$subject->currentCert['tbsCertificate']['extensions'][] = array(
   'extnId' => 'id-ce-subjectAltName',
   'critical' => false,
   'extnValue' => $extnValues
);
```